# How to execute journey exists in child BU from parent automation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, ssjs, automationstudio

I need to execute a journey which is created in child BU from parent automation. The automation option is disabled in Schedule Type in the child journey even the data extension is used in the parent automation.

Thanks,
Prasad

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the journey in the child BU will recognize the automation in the parent BU since they are 2 different BUs.

---

**Updated** based on [Lukas Lunow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/36623/lukas-lunow)'s idea from the comment.

Normally, in this scenario, when the data source is provided by the parent BU and the child BU is the one that needs to execute the automation (from its BU), I would use a script activity in the last step from the parent automation to trigger a separate automation in the child BU, hence pulling the data and triggering the journey in the child BU.

Specifically, the data source in the parent BU will be put in a shared data extension folder (I am sure this is what you already did)

**In the child BU:**

You can make a separate DE that will be used for the data source in the journey and a separate automation that will be used to trigger the journey.

So the automation activities in the child BU will include something like: SQL to pull from the shared DE to the separate DE above, Verification activity to check records number, and Journey Entry audience when you set up Schedule Type for the journey.

Note: This automation needs to be configured with an empty schedule.

**In the parent BU:**

I would write a script activity and put it at the last step in the parent automation so this script can call the automation in the child BU

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
// Impersonate to the Child BU
    prox.setClientId({"ID":"Your child BU MID"}); // Child BU MID
var automationCustKey =  "Your automation custom key" // Automation custom key in the child BU

var action = "Start";
var props = {CustomerKey: automationCustKey};
var opts = {};
var data = prox.performItem("Automation", props, action, opts);
//Write(Stringify(data));
</script>
```

Comment: A better approach would be to trigger the automation in child BU with an SSJS step in the parent automation. This will ensure that the automation/journey in child BU is not run if something went wrong in the parent automation leading to the data not being refreshed

Comment: Great idea @LukasLunow, I will update the answer based on this idea!